# Inserting text of length > 4681 characters results in empty table field with no error message

Tags: postgresql, text, insert, field, postgresql-9.2

I am facing a strange bug. I have a table in Postgresql with a `text` field `"txtj"`. I also have a function that populates this table with:

```
INSERT INTO "precomputed" ("stmt","param","slice","txtj","crea","exp")
     VALUES (statement_name,parametr,sliice,textj,creation,expiration);
```

When `"txtj"` has a character length of 4681 at most, the field is populated correctly. But, if it has more characters, the field is left blank, with no error message raised. I could find this number by checking with substrings:

```
textj := substring(textj from 0 for 4681);
```

Why? Is there a restriction on the length of text fields? My textj contains about 7500 characters. How can I solve this issue

**UPDATE**

I can replicate this issue from pgAdmin III's SQL console using the following script (I am under windows 7):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "test" (i integer, ttt text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fill_test()
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    ffill text = '';
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE "test";
    FOR i IN 0..250 LOOP
        INSERT INTO "test" VALUES ((i*20),ffill);
        ffill := ffill || '01234567890123456789';
    END LOOP;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT fill_test();
SELECT * FROM "test" ORDER BY "i";
```

Above 4680, the fields are empty...

**UPDATE II**

`select version()` returns:

```
"PostgreSQL 9.2.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit"
```

pgAdmin's version: `1.16.1`

Comment: Is there anything in the PostgreSQL server log?  What is the exact version of PostgreSQL? `select version()`  I suspect what you have is a pgAdmin issue, not a PostgreSQL issue.  What is the version of pgAdmin?

Comment: I have just updated my question with the information

Comment: Last message in log is 5 hours old and unrelated to this issue. Any way I can test your theory?

Comment: I'd set the server's log_statements to 'all', restart it, run your test case and see what ends up in the log.  (I can't reproduce the issue in 9.3.2 / 1.18.1).

Comment: You're right, it is a pgAdmin issue, I managed to test it with a small node application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the records, there is no bug on Postgresql' side. I have managed to retrieve the field value correctly using a small node app connected to the database.

I am leaving this answer as info for others. According to jjanes, the issue does not happen in 9.3.2 / 1.18.1.

Comment: A bizarre issue nonetheless. I think PgAdmin-III gets less testing than it could because most experienced users use `psql`.